# Disable touches/scroll during processing

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an application containing a UIScrollView with Paging=YES and with the following test code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    sleep(1);
}
```

If the user performs several swipes during this 1 second sleep, all the swipe events are performed once the main thread has been freed - giving a "wild" effect.

Is there a way to disable touches/swipes while this blocking work is being performed (of course the ideal is to not block the main thread here, but not always possible!).

I have tried to wrap the 'sleep' with `setUserInteraction = NO / YES` and `setScrollingEnabled = NO  / YES` but without any luck.

Comment: What are you doing in the mainThread else so it is full of load?

Comment: The delay isn't really 1 second - just for the demo. It may be very short, but still, any swipes performed while some work is being performed causes this behaviour.

Comment: Well whatever you, you should move the processing to a seperate thread so the scrollview stays responsive.

Comment: Unfortunately that answer does not solve my problem...

Comment: It's no answer, it's a comment, and your question tries to solve the problem in a certain way. I am trying to figure out if the code design does allow a better more elegant solution. I just try to help...

Comment: Help greatly appreciated! The problem is during some milliseconds of wirk, but there seems to be a problem started in iOS 4.3 which sometimes causes the "cached" swipe event to cause wild behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

My friend had this problem when she wanted to disable taps after an action for a specified period of time. What you want to do is leverage the NSObject's performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(enableUserInteraction) withObject:nil afterDelay: 1];
}

- (void)enableUserInteraction {
    userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

This is rough as I likely don't have the syntax right, but you ought to be able to follow this, and you can use it wherever you deem fit. Disable user interaction, then set up a timer event to call a function to reenable it after a specified period of time.